# how can I print to STDOUT in perl module if it is redirected in main script

Tags: perl, stdout

I have redirected `STDOUT` in a Perl script. Everything I print in my module is redirected to a file. Is there a way to restore `STDOUT` in a Perl module?

Here is my example

```
require my_module;

open(STDOUT, ">$outlog") || die "Error stdout: $!";
open(STDERR, ">>$outlog") || die "Error stderr: $!";

my_module::my_func();
```

So I want to print a message on `STDOUT` in `my_module::my_func()` function and exit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I restore STDOUT after redirecting it to a file in a Perl script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585376/how-can-i-restore-stdout-after-redirecting-it-to-a-file-in-a-perl-script)

Answer (score 2):

Seems I found solution. First I saved `STDOUT` in main script then I used it in module.

```
require my_module;
open(SAVEOUT, ">&STDOUT") || die "Unable to save STDOUT: $!";
open(STDOUT, ">$outlog") || die "Error stdout: $!";

open(STDERR, ">>$outlog") || die "Error stderr: $!";

my_module::my_func();
```

In `my_module::my_func()` I added the following line before exiting

```
open (STDOUT, ">&main::SAVEOUT") or die "Unable to restore STDOUT : $!";
print "a_module!!!\n";
```

My printed message was sent to `STDOUT`

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can't restore STDOUT unless you save it at some other location.

You can do following:

```
        # Save current STDOUT handle in OLDOUT
        open (OLDOUT, ">&STDOUT") or die "Can't open OLDOUT: $!";   

        # Set STDOUT to a your output file
        open (STDOUT, ">$youroutputfile") or die "Can't open STDOUT: $!";

        # Do whatever you want to do here.......
        # ...........

        # Close STDOUT output stream
        close (STDOUT);

        # Reset STDOUT stream to previous state
        open (STDOUT, ">&OLDOUT") or die "Can't open STDOUT: $!";

        # Close OLDOUT handle
        close (OLDOUT);

        # Here your preview STDOUT is restored....
```

:)